# TransactionScope error: HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting this error in my transaction scope object.
The circled line in the picture raises this error: "HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: DTC?....................

Comment: Yes. I played with the local DTC settings. no success.